# Does the Holy Spirit speak on behalf of the Father , or the Son or both?

Tags: catholicism, trinity, gospel-of-john, acts, spirit

We see in John 16:13,  Jesus giving his disciples a foresight into the role of the Holy Spirit:

> When the Spirit of truth comes, he will guide you into all the truth; for he will not speak on his own, but will speak whatever he hears, and he will declare to you the things that are to come.

Elsewhere, we see Jesus telling :

> For I have not spoken on my own, but the Father who sent me has himself given me a commandment about what to say and what to speak." - Jn 12:49.

And we also see at Acts 16:7.

> When they had come opposite Mysia, they attempted to go into Bithynia, but the Spirit of Jesus did not allow them...

My question therefore is: **According to Catholic Church, does the Holy Spirit speak on behalf of the  Father or the Son or both?And, does the Holy Spirit speak for himself?**

Comment: The Father, Son, and Holy Spirit, although they are distinct persons, are one God, and  thus they share one divine will. Although in speech we may attribute an act to one of the Persons in particular (for example, the Holy Spirit inspires the prophets or the Father creates the world), in the most literal sense every act of God is done by all Persons of the Trinity together. So when you ask whether the Holy Spirit speaks on behalf of the Father or Son, you are making the false assumption that the Father and Son are not also speaking, when in reality the Trinity is speaking with one will.